# Bootstrap Accordion not working properly in React

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

So I copy pasted the exact same code for Accordion from Bootstrap, but the style is completely different, and it doesn't function.

**The code of About.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function About() {

  return (
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Accordion Item #1
            </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Accordion Item #2
            </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Accordion Item #3
            </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
```

}

**The code of App.js:**

```
import About from './components/About';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container my-3">
      <About/>
    </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**How it's supposed to look like:**
[The bootstrap accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1jYg.png)

**How it actually looks:**
[The accordion on my React App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BImEg.png)

And I don't think there are any typos in importing it or in using it anywhere else. I also made sure to include the Bootstrap CSS link.

Comment: Could you please try to provide a fully functional React snippet in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a complete beginner, so I don't understand what you mean by "fully functional snippet" 

I mean, I have already provided the files which I thought were relevant to my problem. 

So again, I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

```
{/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/}

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I think you are not using it the right way, you should read the docs for React Bootstrap, you're not supposed to copy everything with classnames and such, there are components that you can use that will do that for you, here's the example: react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion

Comment: I'm sorry but  it throws a "module not found" error.

I tried this in both the files.

Comment: Update: So I managed to resolve that error, but the same problem is still there. The accordion is the same as before.

Comment: Are you using React bootstrap? have you used 
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap?

Comment: No, I haven't used that command. I just went into the docs section of the website, and copy pasted the code. But I did do the refactoring later on though, that is, changing "class" to "className", but it didn't change anything. Also, I did the exact same thing for components like Nav bar, textforms, and buttons. and they all worked absolutely fine.

Comment: I think you are not using it the right way, you should read the docs for React Bootstrap, your'e not supposed to copy everything with classnames and such, there are components that you can use that will do that for you, here's the example: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you forgot to import styles in your project...Using CDN link will now work as you need to import styles.
go to https://react-bootstrap.github.io and check for import styles

hope this helps